# Converting raw pointer to 16-bit Unicode character to file path in Rust

Tags: windows, unicode, rust

I'm replacing a DLL written in C++ with one written in Rust.
Currently the function in the DLL is called as follows:

```cpp
BOOL calledFunction(wchar_t* pFileName)
```

I believe that in this context `wchar_t` is a 16-bit Unicode character, so I chose to expose the following function in my Rust DLL:

```
pub fn calledFunction(pFileName: *const u16)
```

What would be the best way to convert that raw pointer to something I could actually use to open the file from the Rust DLL?

Comment: TLDR: [`String::from_utf16`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf16)

Comment: This answer pointed me to a Rust doc I had already considered : https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf16. But then how do I convert this raw pointer to a &[u16] ?

Comment: *I believe that in this context wchar_t is a 16-bit Unicode character* — please don't guess, as your guess is wrong on various platforms. Instead, use [`libc::wchar_t`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.36/libc/type.wchar_t.html) which is correctly defined for the appropriate target platform.

Comment: @Shepmaster Actually, the OP **is** right. `wchar_t` is 16-bit on Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367308(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Boiethios I never said OP was *wrong*, just that hardcoding `wchar_t` as a `u16` on all platforms is a bad choice. C is rather slippery with its type definitions (e.g. "how big is an `int`"). One reason to use Rust in the first place is to avoid these types of issues. Using `libc::wchar_t` will prevent the code from compiling on a different platform, instead of compiling but ending up with mismatched pointers which will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some example code:

```
use std::ffi::OsString;
use std::os::windows::prelude::*;

unsafe fn u16_ptr_to_string(ptr: *const u16) -> OsString {
    let len = (0..).take_while(|&i| *ptr.offset(i) != 0).count();
    let slice = std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len);

    OsString::from_wide(slice)
}

// main example
fn main() {
    let buf = vec![97_u16, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 0];
    let ptr = buf.as_ptr(); // raw pointer

    let string = unsafe { u16_ptr_to_string(ptr) };

    println!("{:?}", string);
}
```

In `u16_ptr_to_string`, you do 3 things:

- get the length of the string by counting the non-zero characters using [`offset`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.offset) (unsafe)
- create a slice using [`from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) (unsafe)
- transform this `&[u16]` into an `OsString` with [`from_wide`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStringExt.html#tymethod.from_wide)

It is better to use [`wchar_t`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.36/libc/type.wchar_t.html) and [`wcslen`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.36/libc/fn.wcslen.html) from the libc crate and use another crate for conversion. This is maybe a bad idea to reimplement something that is already maintained in a crate.

Comment: Might be worth using something that cannot be represented in ASCII as `w`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Why?

Comment: There's plenty of code that "works" until you give it something unexpected. For example, I don't know how this code handles UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

Comment: @Shepmaster That is the `String::from_utf16`'s business.

Comment: @Shepmaster And my "strlen" is ok: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx#Anchor_1

Comment: @trentcl [explains the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586816/converting-raw-pointer-to-16-bit-unicode-character-to-file-path-in-rust/48587463?noredirect=1#comment84173018_48587087) well. (maybe that's different, actually)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164422/discussion-between-boiethios-and-shepmaster).

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [`OsString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html), which represents the native string format used by the operating system. In Windows these are specifically 16-bit character strings (usually UTF-16).

Quoting the doc:

> `OsString` and `OsStr` are useful when you need to transfer strings to and from the operating system itself, or when capturing the output of external commands. Conversions between `OsString`, `OsStr` and Rust strings work similarly to those for `CString` and `CStr`.

You first need to convert the pointer into a slice, using unsafe code:

```
use std::slice;

// manifest a slice out of thin air!
let ptr = 0x1234 as const *u16;
let nb_elements = 10;
unsafe {
    let slice = slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, nb_elements);
}
```

This assumes you know the size of your string, meaning your function should also take the number of characters as argument.

The [`from_wide`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStringExt.html#tymethod.from_wide) method should be the one needed to convert from a native format:

```
use std::ffi::OsString;
use std::os::windows::prelude::*;

// UTF-16 encoding for "Unicode".
let arr = [0x0055, 0x006E, 0x0069, 0x0063, 0x006F, 0x0064, 0x0065];

let string = OsString::from_wide(&arr[..]);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'll investigate that and come back shortly. I can't really change the arguments of the calling function. If I was in C i would use strlen to count the character until the null terminator. I guess I could call strlen from Rust somehow. I'll check is from_wide works appropriately.

Comment: @watts There is probably a different function you have to use, not `strlen`, since `wchar_t` is 16 bits wide and `strlen` assumes no embedded zero bytes.

Comment: `On Windows, strings are often arbitrary sequences of non-zero 16-bit values` So I guess a 0x0000 value can indeed indicate end-of-string.

Comment: Might be worth using something that cannot be represented in ASCII as `arr`. Showing how it handles UTF-16 surrogate pairs would be good too.

Comment: Assuming the string is null-terminated, you still can't use `strlen`. `"Abc\0"` is encoded into little-endian UTF-16 as `[65, 0, 98, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0]`. `strlen` goes byte-by-byte, so it will return 1. You need to use a function that goes two bytes at a time to get the desired value (3).

Comment: @trentcl Yeah I was referring to the appropriate strlen, but thanks for noting that out

Comment: @watts Pedantry is <s>what I do best!</s> one of the things I'm really good at.