# How to convert a Windows API C string pointer into a string?

Tags: winapi, rust, c-strings

I'm trying to get the names of all the windows using

- [winapi](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs)

  - [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows)

    - [`EnumWindowsProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633498(v=vs.85).aspx)
  - [`GetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta)

```
extern crate winapi;

// --- std ---
use std::ffi::CStr;
// --- external ---
use winapi::{
    shared::{minwindef::LPARAM, windef::HWND__},
    um::winuser::{EnumWindows, GetWindowTextA},
};

fn find_window() {
    extern "system" fn enum_windows_proc(hwnd: *mut HWND__, _l_param: LPARAM) -> i32 {
        let ptr = &mut 0;

        unsafe {
            GetWindowTextA(hwnd, ptr as *mut i8, 1024);
            println!("hwnd: {:?}, name: {:?}", hwnd, CStr::from_ptr(ptr));
        }

        1
    }

    unsafe {
        EnumWindows(Some(enum_windows_proc), 0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    find_window();
}
```

I found some solutions:

- [What is the proper way to go from a String to a *const i8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649311/what-is-the-proper-way-to-go-from-a-string-to-a-const-i8)
- [How do I convert a C string into a Rust string and back via FFI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145823/how-do-i-convert-a-c-string-into-a-rust-string-and-back-via-ffi)

But I get something like this:

```
hwnd: 0x100d6, name: ""
hwnd: 0x10250, name: "B \xa3\xd6T\xf7\x7f\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00"
hwnd: 0x10260, name: ""
hwnd: 0x1028a, name: "N \xa3\xd6T\xf7\x7f\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00"
hwnd: 0x10288, name: ""
hwnd: 0x706f8, name: "T \xa3\xd6T\xf7\x7f"
hwnd: 0x1011c, name: ""
hwnd: 0x10510, name: "W \xa3\xd6T\xf7"
hwnd: 0x2037c, name: ""
hwnd: 0x30742, name: "C \xa3\xd6T\xf7\x7f\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
hwnd: 0x12019c, name: "M \xa3\xd6T\xf7\x7f\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00"
hwnd: 0x90754, name: "C \xa3\xd6T\xf7\x7f\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
hwnd: 0x1004e4, name: "M \xa3\xd6T\xf7\x7f\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

Obviously, all the names are wrong. 
How could I get the string from `ptr`?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Calling the GetUserName WinAPI function with a mutable string doesn't populate the string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44709780/155423) and [What is the right way to allocate data to pass to an FFI call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39550856/155423). If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR: `let ptr = &mut 0;` is completely and totally wrong. You never allocate any space to store the string in; this is a pointer to an `i32` which is 4 bytes long.

Comment: You might as well switch to `GetWindowTextW` to handle non-ASCII names as well.

Comment: Thanks your tips. I did't notice the allocation. After I change the`ptr` to `let name = Vec::with_capacity(1024); let ptr = name.as_ptr();`, it works.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks ^ ^, this question can be closed.

Comment: @Shepmaster I got some problems when I switch to `GetWindowTextW`. It takes a `u16 ptr`, I can't get the text from `CStr::from_ptr(ptr)`. Could you help me?

Comment: [Convert it to a slice and use `OsString`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48587087/155423)